# Using Optional Parameters in where clause in symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-1.4

How can i use optional parameters for a WHERE Clause of a select query using symfony query builder.

Ex.

In php,

$userid = (empty())?' Where userid='.$userid:''

Qry : "SELECT * FROM users ".$userid

Similarly, in symfony, how can i use optional parameter in Where Clause using CreateQueryBuilder????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your repository or where you make your QB:

```
// this works in EntityRepository
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder(); 
// otherwise $em instanceof EntityManager
// $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
$qb
    ->select('ss, ls')
    ->innerJoin('ss.linkSomething', 'ls')
    ->where('ss.fieldOne = 1')
;
// $one is your first condition
if($one){
    $qb->andWhere('ss.fieldTwo = 2');
}
// $two is your second condition
if($two){
    $qb->andWhere('ls.fieldOne = 1');
}
```

Just create QueryBuilder instance once and start to add any JOINs or WHEREs to it in any combination you want for the entities you select and joins you made.

After that ***don't forget*** to:

```
//setup params, if they're in query    
$qb->setParameters($arrParam);
//to check sql
// $sql = $qb->getQuery()->getSql();
//to check Dql
// $dql = $qb->getQuery()->getDql();
//result
$res = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();// any result method you need by doctrine documentation
```

**Upd:**
For more information just [read this documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html), it's full of easy examples.

Comment: You asked how to write query builder (QB) with "optional parameter in Where Clause" - that is it. $one, $two is your conditions which allow\disallow you to put another "where" to QB.

Comment: Yeah i understand now. Tx a lot.